# Failed to call a websocket send function on beforeunload event when page closes

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I'm trying to use this piece of code to send a websocket message to the back-end when a page is closed.

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => 
    {  
        ev.preventDefault();
        const message = {
            socket_type: "PARTICIPANT",
            data: {
                sender_participant_id: token,
                action_type: "LEAVE"
            }
        }
        ws.send(message);
        return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?';
    });
  }, []);
```

If I don't include `ws.send(message)`, I'll have a popup window asking "Are you sure you want to close" as expected, but when I add ws.send(message), the window just closes. No popup, no message received by backend. Since it just closes, I cannot track what happend then. Note that the `ws.send` part is tested in other parts of the code, so itself can't be wrong.

Can someone help? Thanks!